# Installing Sage, when as root it complains, when not as root it complains

Tags: software-installation, sage-math

I just downloaded the tarball for Sage from here: http://mirrors.mit.edu/sage/linux/64bit/index.html

I then unzipped it with `bunzip2` which created a folder `/SageMath` so I cd into that.  Then I run `sudo make` and it tells me that I cannot make as root,

```
configure: error: You cannot build Sage as root, switch to an unpriviledged user
```

So then I just run `make` and it complains

```
./configure: line 2107: config.log: Permission denied
./configure: line 2117: config.log: Permission denied
```

So it kind of seems like a catch-22.  Weirdly, in few or none of the instructions I've found did they even say to run `make`, they just said to enter the command `sage` which also throws an error and requests that you run `make`.  So I've found this whole process very confusing.

Comment: Presumably you unzipped it as root (since the target directory was `/`)? Try starting over, but unzipping it in your unprivileged user's home directory, **without** `sudo`

Comment: @steeldriver Yep, that did it.  Now it complains `Makefile:31: recipe for target 'base-toolchain' failed` and I can't find any info about that error.  I think I downloaded all the prerequisites, which is my only guess about why I'd get this error.  I can make a separate question if that's best.

Answer (score 0):

You did a bunch of steps as root before you ran `make`, so now `make` doesn't have permission to write files it needs to write, since root owns things that you need to own. Either chown -R the whole SageMath directory to yourself, or just delete it all and start over without doing anything as root.